# I am willing to compare and match each object sequentially in two JSONs and report mismatches in the report, can we do this natively in karate?

Tags: karate

Basically want to achieve something like the below, was thinking if I can do this natively

```
const obj1Keys = Object.keys(jsonData1);
const obj1Values = Object.values(jsonData1);
const obj2Keys = Object.keys(jsonData2);
const obj2Values = Object.values(jsonData2);

for (let i = 0; i < obj1Keys.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < obj2Keys.length; j++) {
    if (obj1Keys[i] === obj2Keys[j]) {
      if (obj1Values[2] !== obj2Values[2]) {
        alert("data mismatched");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

}

Below returns a failure if one of the objects is not matching but it doesn't indicate which one it is

```
* match jsonData1 == jsonData2
```

Comment: also read the comments under the linked Q&A